# Cordova iOS source files not in UTF-8 after compilation

Tags: ios, cordova, encoding

I develop a Cordova aplication for iOS. I use UTF8 for all of my source codes files. I use VS Code for writing and XCode for compilation. Both of them show my source files correctly:

VS Code

[image]

XCode ( I event set manually encoding of the file )

[image]

Once the application is compiled and loaded to my phone, the files are interpreted in some different encoding ( this picture comes from Safari debuger )

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found the solution. It is necessary to add

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

to index.html.